# I am trying to add a water mark on video, I did it in objective c but its showing lot of errors in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, watermark

```
> - (void) createWatermark:(UIImage*)image video:(NSURL*)videoURL
{
    if (videoURL == nil)
        return;

    AppDelegate* appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    //[appDelegate showLoadingView: YES];

    AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:videoURL options:nil];
    AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

    AVMutableCompositionTrack* compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo  preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

    AVAssetTrack* clipVideoTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration)
                                   ofTrack:clipVideoTrack
                                    atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

    [compositionVideoTrack setPreferredTransform:[[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] preferredTransform]];

    //  create the layer with the watermark image
    CALayer* aLayer = [CALayer layer];
    aLayer.contents = (id)image.CGImage;
    aLayer.frame = CGRectMake(50, 100, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    aLayer.opacity = 0.9;

    //sorts the layer in proper order

    AVAssetTrack* videoTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    CGSize videoSize = [videoTrack naturalSize];
    CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
    CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
    parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
    videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
    [parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
    [parentLayer addSublayer:aLayer];

    // create text Layer
    CATextLayer* titleLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
    titleLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    titleLayer.string = @"Dummy text";
    titleLayer.font = CFBridgingRetain(@"Helvetica");
    titleLayer.fontSize = 28;
    titleLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
    titleLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;
    titleLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, videoSize.width, videoSize.height / 6);
    [parentLayer addSublayer:titleLayer];

    //create the composition and add the instructions to insert the layer:

    AVMutableVideoComposition* videoComp = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
    videoComp.renderSize = videoSize;
    videoComp.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
    videoComp.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];

    /// instruction
    AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction* instruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];

    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [mixComposition duration]);
    AVAssetTrack* mixVideoTrack = [[mixComposition tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction* layerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:mixVideoTrack];
    instruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:layerInstruction];
    videoComp.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject: instruction];

    // export video

    _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
    _assetExport.videoComposition = videoComp;

    NSLog (@"created exporter. supportedFileTypes: %@", _assetExport.supportedFileTypes);

    NSString* videoName = @"NewWatermarkedVideo.mov";

    NSString* exportPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:videoName];
    NSURL* exportUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportPath];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:exportPath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:exportPath error:nil];

    _assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    _assetExport.outputURL = exportUrl;
    _assetExport.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;

    [_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(void ) {

         //[appDelegate showLoadingView:NO];

         //Final code here

         switch (_assetExport.status)
         {
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusUnknown:
                 NSLog(@"Unknown");
                 break;
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting:
                 NSLog(@"Waiting");
                 break;
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting:
                 NSLog(@"Exporting");
                 break;
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
                 NSLog(@"Created new water mark image");
                 playBtn.hidden = NO;
                 break;
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                 NSLog(@"Failed- %@", _assetExport.error);
                 break;
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                 NSLog(@"Cancelled");
                 break;
         }
     }
     ];   
}
>  Use of unresolved identifier 'presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated'
> 
> 'videoComposition()' is unavailable: use object construction 'AVMutableVideoComposition()'
```

> Enum case 'unknown' not found in type 'AVAssetExportSessionStatus?'
>   It is working very fine in Objective C
>    Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads
>   These are the few errors I am getting while doing in swift
>   I am totally new to swift, any help?

Comment: You have said you are getting errors in your swift code, although you have not provided any example of swift code. All the code is in objective-C which you say works fine. To help us best answer your question please provide an example of your broken swift code.

Answer (score 0):

**YOUR SWIFT 3.0 VERSION:**

```
func createWatermark(_ image: UIImage, video videoURL: URL) 
    {
                if videoURL == nil 
    {
                    return
                }
                let appDelegate: AppDelegate? = UIApplication.shared.delegate
                //[appDelegate showLoadingView: YES];
                let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL, options: nil)
                let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()
                let compositionVideoTrack: AVMutableCompositionTrack? = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
                let clipVideoTrack: AVAssetTrack? = (videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] as? AVAssetTrack)
                try? compositionVideoTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), of: clipVideoTrack, atTime: kCMTimeZero)
                compositionVideoTrack?.preferredTransform = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0].preferredTransform
            }



    //  create the layer with the watermark image
    var aLayer = CALayer()
    aLayer.contents = (image.cgImage as? Any)
    aLayer.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(50), y: CGFloat(100), width: CGFloat(image.size.width), height: CGFloat(image.size.height))
    aLayer.opacity = 0.9

    //sorts the layer in proper order
    var videoTrack: AVAssetTrack? = (videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] as? AVAssetTrack)
    var videoSize: CGSize? = videoTrack?.naturalSize
    var parentLayer = CALayer()
    var videoLayer = CALayer()
    parentLayer.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(videoSize?.width), height: CGFloat(videoSize?.height))
    videoLayer.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(videoSize?.width), height: CGFloat(videoSize?.height))
    parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
    parentLayer.addSublayer(aLayer)

        // create text Layer
    var titleLayer = CATextLayer()
    titleLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    titleLayer.string = "Dummy text"
    titleLayer.font = CFBridgingRetain("Helvetica")
    titleLayer.fontSize = 28
    titleLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    titleLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter
    titleLayer.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(50), width: CGFloat(videoSize.width), height: CGFloat(videoSize.height / 6))
    parentLayer.addSublayer(titleLayer)

    //create the composition and add the instructions to insert the layer:
    var videoComp = AVMutableVideoComposition.videoComposition
    videoComp.renderSize = videoSize
    videoComp.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
    videoComp.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAs: videoLayer, in: parentLayer)

  /// instruction
var instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction.videoCompositionInstruction
instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, mixComposition.duration)
var mixVideoTrack: AVAssetTrack? = (mixComposition.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] as? AVAssetTrack)
var layerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(mixVideoTrack)
instruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]
videoComp.instructions = [instruction]

// export video
assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality)
assetExport.videoComposition = videoComp
print("created exporter. supportedFileTypes: \(assetExport.supportedFileTypes)")
var videoName: String = "NewWatermarkedVideo.mov"
var exportPath: String = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(videoName).absoluteString
var exportUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: exportPath)
if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: exportPath) {
    try? FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: exportPath)
}
assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
assetExport.outputURL = exportUrl
assetExport.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true


assetExport.exportAsynchronously(withCompletionHandler: {(_: Void) -> Void in
    //[appDelegate showLoadingView:NO];
    //Final code here
    switch assetExport.status {
        case .unknown:
            print("Unknown")
        case .waiting:
            print("Waiting")
        case .exporting:
            print("Exporting")
        case .completed:
            print("Created new water mark image")
            playBtn.isHidden = false
        case .failed:
            print("Failed- \(assetExport.error)")
        case .cancelled:
            print("Cancelled")
    }

})
```